# How to convert all array/object with base64

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, base64

Actually i figure it out how to convert all items inside an object or an array.
Let me show you my way:

```
var copyData = {};
var data = {
        "1":[["input","Was spielt Jakob gern?"],["input sag alt",["Jakob", "Er", " spielt nicht gern Basketball."]]],
        "2":[["input alt",["Lena", "Sie", " chattet gern."]],["input sag","Was macht Lena nicht gern?"]],
        "3":[["input alt",["Meike", "Sie", " sieht gern fern."]],["input sag","Was macht Meike nicht gern?"]],
        "4":[["input","Was spielt Tim gern?"],["input sag alt",["Tim", "Er", " spielt nicht gern Fußball."]]],
        "5":[["input","Was spielt Simon gern?"],["input sag","Was spielt Simon nicht gern?"]],
        "6":[["input alt",["Melanie", "Sie", " tanzt gern Hip Hop."]],["input sag","Was tanzt Melanie nicht gern?"]]
    };
```

My Object is the one named data. Here is my for loop's to convert this object into another with each element encoded.

```
for(var i in data){
    copyData[i] = [];
    for(var j in data[i]){
        copyData[i][j] = [];
        for(var g in data[i][j]){
            if(typeof data[i][j][g] == "string"){
                copyData[i][j][g] = btoa(data[i][j][g]);
            } else {
                copyData[i][j][g] = [];
                for(var b in data[i][j][g]){
                    copyData[i][j][g][b] = btoa(data[i][j][g][b]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And if u want to console that copyData Object you can use this :

```
console.debug(JSON.stringify(dd));
```

The result is this:

```
var copyData = {
    "1":[["aW5wdXQ=","V2FzIHNwaWVsdCBKYWtvYiBnZXJuPw=="],["aW5wdXQgc2FnIGFsdA==",["SmFrb2I=","RXI=","IHNwaWVsdCBuaWNodCBnZXJuIEJhc2tldGJhbGwu"]]],
    "2":[["aW5wdXQgYWx0",["TGVuYQ==","U2ll","IGNoYXR0ZXQgZ2Vybi4="]],["aW5wdXQgc2Fn","V2FzIG1hY2h0IExlbmEgbmljaHQgZ2Vybj8="]],
    "3":[["aW5wdXQgYWx0",["TWVpa2U=","U2ll","IHNpZWh0IGdlcm4gZmVybi4="]],["aW5wdXQgc2Fn","V2FzIG1hY2h0IE1laWtlIG5pY2h0IGdlcm4/"]],
    "4":[["aW5wdXQ=","V2FzIHNwaWVsdCBUaW0gZ2Vybj8="],["aW5wdXQgc2FnIGFsdA==",["VGlt","RXI=","IHNwaWVsdCBuaWNodCBnZXJuIEZ132JhbGwu"]]],
    "5":[["aW5wdXQ=","V2FzIHNwaWVsdCBTaW1vbiBnZXJuPw=="],["aW5wdXQgc2Fn","V2FzIHNwaWVsdCBTaW1vbiBuaWNodCBnZXJuPw=="]],
    "6":[["aW5wdXQgYWx0",["TWVsYW5pZQ==","U2ll","IHRhbnp0IGdlcm4gSGlwIEhvcC4="]],["aW5wdXQgc2Fn","V2FzIHRhbnp0IE1lbGFuaWUgbmljaHQgZ2Vybj8="]]
};
```

**So everything is okey so far. My question is: Is there any array prototype to do this job easier. I look up to Array.prototype.map() but that uses regular arrays or object with out dimention.
Is there any easy way to do this or should i use this way all the time :)
Thanks for Advance.**

Comment: @Rajesh actually I think this is one of those cases where it might be appropriate - it would automatically convert any named properties that might exist on an array as well as the numeric indices.

Comment: I have to ask - why on earth do you want to do this?

Comment: Hello @Rajesh thx for reply. I never say that is the best or good way to do this. I just say that this is my way :)

Comment: Hello @Alnitak, I need it because users can't see the direct answer's to questions :)

Comment: @Rajesh in modern browsers `.length` is not an enumerable property

Comment: @Alnitak My apologies. I did not know this.

Comment: @Rajesh Thx for reply again. I know i can use this and i aware about processing time :) I just want to learn is there any faster way to do this :)

Comment: @HalilÇakar do you specifically want a copy of the object, or would an in-place modification be OK ?

Comment: @Alnitak i dont mind if copying or in-place modification both are okey for me :)

Comment: By the @Rajesh i need to correct myself. I need an easy way to this not faster sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look for a recursive solution:

```
function encodeString(obj) {
    let type = typeof obj;
    if (type === 'object') {
        for (let key in obj) {
             obj[key] = encodeString(obj[key]);
        }
    } else if (type === 'string') {
        obj = btoa(obj);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

This will modify the object in place.

Whilst arguably one shouldn't use `for ... in` on array objects, I think the use here is justifiable because it simplifies the code and if any (enumerable) string properties were on the array you'd want them updated too.   It used to be the case that `for ... in` would also enumerate an array's `.length` property but in modern browsers that's no longer the case.

If you want a version that doesn't modify in place:

```
function encodeString(obj) {
    let type = typeof obj;
    if (type === 'object') {
        let tmp = Array.isArray(obj) ? [] : {};
        for (let key in obj) {
             tmp[key] = encodeString(obj[key]);
        }
        return tmp;
    } else if (type === 'string') {
        return btoa(obj);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

but note that this is *not* a completely safe function - it'll produce "interesting" results if passed objects that aren't plain data because it doesn't deep clone everything.

Comment: I believe this one function can't convert all my data? can u write try to convert that data variable which i wrote on the top of this page.

Comment: @HalilÇakar I'll test again, but it appeared to work when I tried it

Comment: Oww well i just try it out and it WORKS PERFECT. Thank you @Alnitak

Comment: Since this is a very generic code, I'd suggest using a `temp` variable and manipulate & return it. Overriding `obj` might not be desired in other case.

Comment: @Rajesh that would in general be preferred, but it would complicate the code somewhat because the initial value of the `temp` variable would sometimes be `[]` and other times be `{}`

Comment: @Alnitak just copy object being sent using Object.assign

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @[Alnitak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782/alnitak)'s answer, you can use `array.reduce` with `array.map` recursively.

```js
var data = {
  "1":[["input","Was spielt Jakob gern?"],["input sag alt",["Jakob", "Er", " spielt nicht gern Basketball."]]],
  "2":[["input alt",["Lena", "Sie", " chattet gern."]],["input sag","Was macht Lena nicht gern?"]],
  "3":[["input alt",["Meike", "Sie", " sieht gern fern."]],["input sag","Was macht Meike nicht gern?"]],
  "4":[["input","Was spielt Tim gern?"],["input sag alt",["Tim", "Er", " spielt nicht gern Fußball."]]],
  "5":[["input","Was spielt Simon gern?"],["input sag","Was spielt Simon nicht gern?"]],
  "6":[["input alt",["Melanie", "Sie", " tanzt gern Hip Hop."]],["input sag","Was tanzt Melanie nicht gern?"]]
};

var output = Object.keys(data).reduce(function(p,c){
  p[c] = btoaArray(data[c]);
  return p;
}, {});

function btoaArray(arr){
  return arr.map(function(item){
    return Array.isArray(item) ? btoaArray(item) : btoa(item)
  })
}

console.log(output)
```

#### ES6 version

```js
var data = {
  "1":[["input","Was spielt Jakob gern?"],["input sag alt",["Jakob", "Er", " spielt nicht gern Basketball."]]],
  "2":[["input alt",["Lena", "Sie", " chattet gern."]],["input sag","Was macht Lena nicht gern?"]],
  "3":[["input alt",["Meike", "Sie", " sieht gern fern."]],["input sag","Was macht Meike nicht gern?"]],
  "4":[["input","Was spielt Tim gern?"],["input sag alt",["Tim", "Er", " spielt nicht gern Fußball."]]],
  "5":[["input","Was spielt Simon gern?"],["input sag","Was spielt Simon nicht gern?"]],
  "6":[["input alt",["Melanie", "Sie", " tanzt gern Hip Hop."]],["input sag","Was tanzt Melanie nicht gern?"]]
};

var output = Object.keys(data).reduce((p,c)=>(p[c] = btoaArray(data[c]), p), {});

function btoaArray(arr){
  return arr.map((item) => Array.isArray(item) ? btoaArray(item) : btoa(item))
}

console.log(output)
```